# Add extra row from distinct in select

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add distinct data to become add as an extra row, which basically will become the "header" (hd) row....

```
gn |  hd  |  item*  
A  |  No  |  Widget One  
A  |  No  |  Widget Two  
A  |  No  |  Widget Three  
B  |  No  |  Widget One  
B  |  No  |  Widget Two  
B  |  No  |  Widget Three  
C  |  No  |  Widget One  
C  |  No  |  Widget Two  
C  |  No  |  Widget Three
```

Turned Into...

```
gn |  hd  |  item 
A  |  Yes |  *NULL*  
A  |  No  |  Widget One  
A  |  No  |  Widget Two  
A  |  No  |  Widget Three  
B  |  Yes |  *NULL*  
B  |  No  |  Widget One  
B  |  No  |  Widget Two  
B  |  No  |  Widget Three  
C  |  Yes |  *NULL*  
C  |  No  |  Widget One  
C  |  No  |  Widget Two  
C  |  No  |  Widget Three
```

This needs to be done with a varying amount of distinct group names (gn) and varying amount of items (it)
I'm guessing I need to SORT BY DESC first, add in the extra rows, then SORT BY ASC.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` and conditional sorting for the results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT gn, 'Yes' hd, null item
FROM tablename
UNION ALL
SELECT gn, hd, item
FROM tablename
ORDER BY gn, item IS NULL DESC, item
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=19cad7caf4c968abd0e185c341024281).
Results:

| gn | hd | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Yes | null |
| A | No | Widget One |
| A | No | Widget Three |
| A | No | Widget Two |
| B | Yes | null |
| B | No | Widget One |
| B | No | Widget Three |
| B | No | Widget Two |
| C | Yes | null |
| C | No | Widget One |
| C | No | Widget Three |
| C | No | Widget Two |

Note that the order in the column `item` is alphabetical because it is a `VARCHAR` column, so `'Widget Two'` is placed after `'Widget Three'`.
If there is a primary key in your table, like `id`, it could be used instead of or with `item` in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: This is perfect. TY